# Use jQuery to get a PDF load ready state

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an embedded pdf using an object tag.  I want to know when the object's readyState==4 (or whatever)

I find jQuery's ready() but that looks like it only works on document load.

Other code out there seems to just loop through checking the ready sate, but that seems a little hacky to me.

Is there a nice clean way to do something like:

```
$("#pdfObject").onStateChange = function(state) {
   if(state==4) ....
}
```

you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution (tested in Chrome and FF) would be to embed the pdf in an iframe and listen for the iframe's load event (shown inline for simplicity). However, this does not seem to work in IE, so if I were you, I'd just stick to polling for `readyState`

```
<iframe 
    src="http://www.epa.gov/region10/pdf/ph/sitewide/bera_draft_final_7-1-2011.pdf"
    onload="alert('done')"></iframe>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8x5AA/

Answer (score -1):

jQuery does not know if pdf document has loaded, i would suggest using another library that can help you out with PDF documents, check you http://pdfobject.com/ and you can find out if the document has been rendered by calling

```
PDFObject.embed(targetID)
```

Comment: That method's documentation says "Returns boolean indicating whether navigator.plugins version of Adobe Reader has been found."

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not tell you that the pdf has finished loading... only that it the object tag has been added to the page